# Ubuntu 20.04.01 and Ubuntu 20.04.02 on my desktop?

Tags: upgrade, versions

It seems to me I miss something.

`lsb_release`, `/etc/issue` File, `/etc/os-release`, `hostnamectl` and in the Ubuntu interface `Settings` > `About`, I return - Ubuntu **20.04.02 LTS** - as Ubuntu long version

But, the last Ubuntu release is 20.04.1 LTS
(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes)

and, with

```
jre@jre:~$ apt show firefox
Package: firefox
Version: 84.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
...
```

This command references **20.04.1** ?!

Thank you for your feedback

--- Oups! Edited ---

`uname -a` return `20.04.1`

```
jre@jre:~$ uname -a `20.04.1`
Linux jre 5.8.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:52:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Not as mentioned in my initial message.

--- end of edited ---

jrd10.

Comment: Ubuntu release dates (for point releases) refer to the ISO release date. The Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS ISO hasn't been released (it's scheduled for this thursday), but installed systems will already have upgraded to be using it, as is normal.  Package names however are **not** the same thing, ie. you're comparing a firefox package name, to the release name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ok now :)

```
jrd_10@my-pc:~$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
```

Thank you for your time.
I do not know why it has been upgraded !

Happy new year with 22.04.0

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu release dates (for point releases) refer to the ISO release date. The Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS ISO hasn't been released (*[it's scheduled for this thursday](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule)*), but installed systems will already have upgraded to be using it, as is normal.

Package names however are **not** the same thing, ie. you're comparing a firefox package name, to the release version.

Your `apt` command is showing the package version which will be according to a standard, but different teams/packagers can use different standards, so unless you're familiar with the team that created the package, don't get fixated on package names. All parts of the "*84.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1*" will have meaning if you break it down, but few of us thankfully have to :)

Comment: > The Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS ISO hasn't been released (*[it's scheduled for this thursday][1]*), but installed systems will already have upgraded to be using it, as is normal.



Thank you for your time.
So you mean, 20.04.02 package has been "upgraded but no installed"?
It is weird that most of release commands do not refer to the "installed" release!
but `uname -a` did it.

So, if I have well understood:
- first, relay on only `uname -a` command
- secondly, after Thursday, all the commands will show `20.04.02`.

Very odd from my humble point of view.

Thank you again.

Comment: No, you are still over-thinking it. Re-read the answer,

Comment: Thank you. It seems to me I have understood :). "84.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1" refer juste the build reference, note the actual version :).